# Group 3Hour data GLDAS to daily results for multiple Sites at the same time to Export as CSV,

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, nasa

I need to extract data from multi Sites, and have a value for each one of them, because they are in differents regions.
This code works, but it gives me only the mean value for all the sites.

How could I ask to have one value/day per each one of them?

It's not a featurecollection, so I really don't know how to code it

```
var startDate = ee.Date('2016-08-01');
var endDate = ee.Date('2017-05-01'); 

// Specify Country names
var lotes = ee.FeatureCollection('users/santiagomol/FTNNN');

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection("NASA/GLDAS/V021/NOAH/G025/T3H")
  .select('Tair_f_inst')
  .filterDate(startDate, endDate);

var list_dataset = dataset.toList(dataset.size());

var getTemperature = function(image) {

  var value_temperat = ee.Image(image)
    .reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.mean(), lotes) //I think this is the problem!!! :S 
    .get('Tair_f_inst');

  return value_temperat;

};

var count = dataset.size();

var temperat_list = dataset.toList(count).map(getTemperature);


//print("Tair_f_inst list", temperat_list);

var len = temperat_list.size();

var list = ee.List.sequence(0, len.subtract(1), 8);

var temp_list = list.map(function(ele){

  var start = ee.Number(ele).int(); 
  var end = ee.Number(ele).add(8).int(); 

  var new_list = ee.List([]);
  var element = ee.List(temperat_list.slice(start, end)).reduce(ee.Reducer.min());

  new_list = new_list.add(element);
  
  var element2 = ee.List(temperat_list.slice(start, end)).reduce(ee.Reducer.max());

  new_list = new_list.add(element2);

  return new_list;

});

print("temp_list", temp_list);

var allDates = ee.List(dataset.aggregate_array('system:time_start'));

var allDatesSimple = allDates.map(function(date){
  return ee.Date(date).format().slice(0,10);
  }).distinct();

print("distinct dates list", allDatesSimple);

var len = temperat_list.size();

//print(len);

var paired = allDatesSimple.zip(temp_list);

print ("paired list", paired);

var myFeatures = ee.FeatureCollection(paired.map(function(el){
  el = ee.List(el); // cast every element of the list
  var geom = lotes;
  return ee.Feature(null, {
    'date': ee.String(el.get(0)),
    'Tmin':ee.Number(ee.List(el.get(1)).get(0)),
    'Tmax':ee.Number(ee.List(el.get(1)).get(1))
  });
}));

//print(myFeatures);

// Export features, specifying corresponding names.
Export.table.toDrive(myFeatures,
"Temperature", //task
"GEE_Folder", //export folder
"daily_temperat",  //file name
"CSV");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is produced because you also have to map by each feature in **lotes** feature collection. As your lotes feature collection is inaccessible by me, I created one by using three arbitrary point geometries in USA. [Code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/77f9552cf45b5589a79b8355516bc4d6) looks as follows. It can be noted that **myFeatures** variable had to be changed for incorporating all features (in your case 273 and now 273x3 = 819) identified by an id (0 for feature 1, 1 for feature 2 and, so on).

```
var startDate = ee.Date('2016-08-01');
var endDate = ee.Date('2017-05-01'); 

// Specify Country names
//var lotes = ee.FeatureCollection('users/santiagomol/FTNNN');

var pt1 = ee.Geometry.Point([-111.283984375, 38.1155715234555]);
var pt2 = ee.Geometry.Point([-101.1765625, 33.48463317512623]);
var pt3 = ee.Geometry.Point([-87.55351562500002, 32.785457836903774]);

var lotes = ee.FeatureCollection([pt1, pt2, pt3]);

print(lotes);

Map.addLayer(lotes, {color:'red'}, "lotes");
Map.centerObject(lotes);

var lotes_lst = lotes.toList(lotes.size());

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection("NASA/GLDAS/V021/NOAH/G025/T3H")
  .select('Tair_f_inst')
  .filterDate(startDate, endDate);

var list_dataset = dataset.toList(dataset.size());

//init function

var groupFeats = lotes_lst.map(function (ele) {
  
  var idx = lotes_lst.indexOf(ele);

  var getTemperature = function(image) {

    var value_temperat = ee.Image(image)
      .reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.mean(), ee.Feature(ele).geometry()) 
      .get('Tair_f_inst');

    return value_temperat;

  };

  var count = dataset.size();

  var temperat_list = dataset.toList(count).map(getTemperature);

  var len = temperat_list.size();

  var list = ee.List.sequence(0, len.subtract(1), 8);

  var temp_list = list.map(function(el){

    var start = ee.Number(el).int(); 
    var end = ee.Number(el).add(8).int(); 

    var new_list = ee.List([]);
    
    new_list = new_list.add(idx);
    
    var element = ee.List(temperat_list.slice(start, end)).reduce(ee.Reducer.min());

    new_list = new_list.add(element);
  
    var element2 = ee.List(temperat_list.slice(start, end)).reduce(ee.Reducer.max());

    new_list = new_list.add(element2);

    return new_list;

  });

  var allDates = ee.List(dataset.aggregate_array('system:time_start'));

  var allDatesSimple = allDates.map(function(date){
    return ee.Date(date).format().slice(0,10);
    }).distinct();

  var paired = allDatesSimple.zip(temp_list);

  return paired;

  }).flatten();

print("groupFeats", groupFeats);

var count = groupFeats.size();

//print("count", count);

var new_list = ee.List.sequence(0, count.subtract(1), 4);

//print("new list", new_list);

var tempValues = new_list.map(function (ele) {
  
    var start = ee.Number(ele).int(); 
    var end = ee.Number(ele).add(4).int();
    
  return ee.List(groupFeats.slice(start, end));
  
});


print("tempValues", tempValues);

var myFeatures = ee.FeatureCollection(tempValues.map(function(el){
  return ee.Feature(null, {
    'date': ee.String(ee.List(el).get(0)),
    'id': ee.Number(ee.List(el).get(1)),
    'Tmin': ee.String(ee.List(el).get(2)),
    'Tmax': ee.String(ee.List(el).get(3))
  });
}));

//print(myFeatures);

// Export features, specifying corresponding names.
Export.table.toDrive(myFeatures,
"Temperature", //task
"GEE_Folder", //export folder
"daily_temperat",  //file name
"CSV");
```

After running it in GEE code editor, I got following result.

[image]

It can be observed that id changed after 273 as expected.

After running the task, produced csv, opened in Libre Office, looks as expected.

[image]

**Editing Note:**

Based in your comment, I added in my point feature collection the column 'Ensayo_Cod' as follows:

```
var Ensayo_Cod = ee.List(['lote 1', 'lote 2', 'lote 3']);

// This function adds lote's name as a property.
var addName = function(ele) {
  var idx = lotes_lst.indexOf(ele);
  return ee.Feature(ele).set({Ensayo_Cod: Ensayo_Cod.get(idx)});
};

lotes_lst = lotes_lst.map(addName);
```

Now, I can modify groupFeats function in new_list variable as:

```
.
.
.

    
    new_list = new_list.add(ee.Feature(ele).get('Ensayo_Cod')); //add lote's names instead id
    
.
.
.
```

Complete code is [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/52e0b029d35055e02d746e8018e17c21). After running the code again, it can be observed that lote's names were added as expected.

[image]

Comment: Thanks !!! The code works perfect but one last question, because I would have more than 200 sites some times, how could I identifie each one of them, insted number 0, 1, 2,3, by the name as string??

Comment: You're welcome. You can do that retrieving the desired property in your lotes feature collection with get instead id. My point feature collection only has id.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but where should I define that? 
If i change the var idx = lotes_lst.indexOf(ele); for the *.get * and defined the column ('Ensayo_Cod'), the system gives me an error (Line 23: Invalid argument specified for ee.Number(): 'Ensayo_Cod'  @xunilk

Comment: Please, see my **Editing Note** for watching as it can be done.

Comment: You really Nailed It.

Thanks a lot for the time and all your help! 

Greatings